# Non-Profit Technology for Non-Profits?

Tags: open-source

I've been looking around for a way to give back to the community, but I haven't found my right fit yet, so an idea came to mind: A non-profit technology "company" that targets non-profits.

Do these exist? I've been doing some google searches and can only find software that is targeted for non-profits that is created by for-profit companies or that charges what I believe to be an outrages amount, conferences directed towards non-profits and technology they may use -- or articles complaining about the digital divide and how non-profits view technology as key but dont have the funds or the knowledge to employ it.

**Pseudo "Business Model"**

An open source 501(3)(c) organization that targets directly targets non-profits to fill the "digital divide." Most services would be free and consulting fees would be charged for customization. Donations would be accepted and government grants would be sought after. This would enable non-profits to keep pace with the for-profits in the technology sector, but at little to no cost. Perhaps the first "industry" to be targeted would be those that fill key social needs like unemployment, or food banks.

Comment: It seems a great idea to me! I do not know of such a company. If I find anything on the topic I will post it.

Comment: I think if developers wish to do non-profit work, they contact the non-profit companies directly and offer their services. I've never heard of an actual non-profit software company that targets non-profits.

Comment: A possibility could be that if you develop a piece of software for one company, that software is open source and can be used for free by other companies. The more software you develop, the more will be available for free. Each time a company pays for a new feature, this new feature becomes available to the whole community.

Comment: My buddy works at the data bank (http://www.thedatabank.com/about.aspx), which is a company that works (I think exclusively) with non-profits, but I don't think that it is a non-profit (so not really what you are looking for, but interesting in so far as they work with non-profits). I think the idea of a non-profit developing open source software and consulting for other non-profits is a pretty neat idea. You could add an education component for the places you work with, which I think helps with 501(3)(c) status and would likely be good for the non-profits as well.

Comment: In my comment above I wrote companies but I meant non-profits. Of course, once a piece of software is open-source, anybody can use it as they see fit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are hordes of already thriving nonprofit technology nonprofits.

Just to get you started:

- [Nonprofit Technology Network](http://www.nten.org/)
- [Social Coding 4 Good](http://www.socialcoding4good.org/)
- [NPower](http://www.npower.org/)

  - [Technology Service Corps](http://technologyservicecorps.org/)
- [Idealware](http://www.idealware.org/)
- [TechSoup](http://home.techsoup.org/)
- [Aspiration](http://www.aspirationtech.org/)
- [Nonprofit Open Source Initiative](http://www.nosi.net/)
- [CiviCRM](http://civicrm.org/)

Comment: *technologyservicecorps.org* and *home.techsoup.org* are now down, and *Nonprofit Open Source Initiative (www.nosi.net)* is now redirected to a traders website.